# Find the equation of the line passing through $(-2,6)$ and parallel to $2y-3x=8$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried many times but have failed in all of them. Help!

The question is:

Find the equation of the line passing through the point $(-2,6)$ and parallel to the line with equation $2y-3x=8$. Express the answer in the form of $y=mx+c$.

I have tried making $x$ zero to get the $y$-coordinate and have made $y$ zero to get the $x$-coordinate. I have also tried to change the equation around to $y=mx+c$ form to no success.

Comment: Are you familiar with the point-slope equation $y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not familiar with this equation though.

Comment: Do you know if two lines are parallel to each other, they have same slope?

Comment: I'm not sure of the way to find the slope from is question

Comment: To get the equation of a line, the slope and a point lying on that line are the minimum requirements. You can get slope from second equation $2y-3x=8$. And point is already given. Here's a small & fun tutorial on straight lines: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html

Comment: Thank you Narendra. Thanks to everyone on helping me, I definitely understand it now

Comment: hope this link helps http://www.readyourtextbook.com

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

Two parallel lines will have the same gradient hence the gradient of the equation of the line passing through $(-2, 6)$ will be $\frac{3}{2}$(see below).

$$ 2y = 3x + 8$$

$$y = \frac{3}{2}x+4$$

Equation of new line(Using $m = \frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}$):

$$ \frac{3}{2} = \frac{y-6}{x+2}$$

$$3(x+2) = 2(y-6)$$

$$ 2y =3x + 18$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

A line parallel to (or coinciding with) $2y-3x=8$ takes the form $2y-3x=c$ for some constant $c$.

The knowledge that $(-2,6)$ is on that line allows you to find $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Equation of line passing through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by,

$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$ where $m$ is slope of the line,
Note that if two lines are parallel to each other , they have same slope, converting your line in slope intercept form we have 
$y=\frac{3}{2}x+8$, hence we have $m=\frac{3}{2}$. Now use the above formula and hint to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A line parallel to $2y - 3x = 8$ will have the same slope.  We can determine the slope of the line $2y - 3x = 8$ by transforming it into slope-intercept form.

\begin{align*}
2y - 3x & = 8\\ 
2y & = 3x + 8\\
y & = \frac{3}{2}x + 4
\end{align*}
Since the equation $y = \frac{3}{2}x + 4$ has the form $y = mx + c$, we see that the line $2x - 3x = 8$ has slope $3/2$.

Thus, the equation of the line parallel to $2y - 3x = 8$ that passes through the point $(-2, 6)$ can be expressed in the form 
$$y = \frac{3}{2}x + c$$
You can determine the value of $c$ by substituting $-2$ for $x$ and $6$ for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers, here is another.

If two functions $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ are parallel then the vertical distance between them is constant so that

$$g(x)=f(x)+c.$$

Note the given line is 
$$f(x)=\frac32x+4.$$

Therefore any parallel line will be of the form

$$g(x)=\frac32x+4+c.$$

Therefore any point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve will satisfy

$$y_0=\frac32x_0+4+c.$$

Write down this equation with $(x_0,y_0)=(-2,6)$.

I find this way of thinking can be helpful with surfaces... two planes of the form

$$f(x,y)=ax+by+c_1\text{ and }g(x,y)=ax+by+c_2$$ 
are parallel because $f=g+(c_1-c_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the equation of the line is of the form $ax+by+c=0.$ Since the line is parallel to the line with equation $2y-3x=8$ the the director vetctor of this line is $3i+2j,$ where $i$ and $j$ are the unitary vectors of the canonical basis in $R^2$ so $a=-2$ and $b=3$ then our equation line must have the form $-2x+3y+c=0.$ Now, to find $c$ we use the point $(-2,6)$ then we get $(-2)\times (-2)+3 \times 6+c=0$ so $c=-22$ we obtain this equation  $-2x+3y-22=0$ which is equivalent to $y=\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{22}{3}.$

Answer (score 0):

> Hint: *the equation of a line parallel to ax+by+c=0 and passing through the point (h,k) is a(x-h)+b(y-k)=0*

Given point ( h, k)=(-2,6)
Given line 2y-3x=8

Required equation is

$2[y-(6)]-3[x-(-2)]=0$

$\implies2y-12-3x-6=0$

$\implies2y=3x+18$

```
Dividing  with 2 on both sides
```

$\implies y=\frac{3}{2}(x)+9$

Now it is in the form $ y=mx+c$

Where $ m=\frac{3}{2} and c=9$

Comment: Not quite right: Your $c$ is different from everyone else's. You solved $b(y - \boldsymbol h) + a(x - \boldsymbol k) = 0$ rather than $b(y - \boldsymbol k) + a(x - \boldsymbol h) = 0$.

Comment: Please also put more effort into the appearance of your posts. Instead of "=>" you can use the math command `\implies`, which yields $\implies$. The line "Divide with 2..." is not the right place to use the code environment. And on the last line you should exit out of math environment around the word "and".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways:

## 1:

If the line is parallel it maintains the coefficients in front of the $x$ and the $y$. So our parallel line equation is:
$$2y-3x = D$$ for some constant $D$. We need to find this value. Let us plug in the point $(-2,6)$ and we get:
$$2\cdot6-3\cdot-2 = D$$
$$D = 18$$
So we get the equation of the line as: $$\boxed{2y-3x = 18}$$

---

## 2:

Convert $2y-3x = 8$ into slope-intercept form ($y=mx+b$) by solving for $y$.
$$2y = 8+3x$$
$$y = \frac{8+3x}{2}$$
$$y = 4+\frac{3}{2}x$$
We know that parallel lines have the same slope so the equation of the line we want to find is in the form:
$$y = \frac{3}{2}x+b$$
Let's plug in $(-2,6)$:
$$6 = \frac{3}{2} \cdot -2 +b$$
$$6 = -3+b$$
$$b = 9$$
So now we have the value of $b$ and the equation of the line we need to find:
$$\boxed{y = \frac{3}{2}x+9}$$
Note that this is equal to the equation $2y-3x=18$ that we obtained from method #1; it is just in a different form.